# How to export SQL to Excel in Python with merged cells

Tags: mysql, excel

I would like to Export SQL to Excel in MySQL with merged cells,

```
SELECT
    name,
    code,
    avg(amount_a),
    avg(amount_b),
    count(*) as total_person
FROM table_test n
GROUP BY code,name,
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

and I tried to use the above SQL get below data,

```
name    code    avg(amount_a)  avg(amount_b)
---------------------------------------------
alice   ab11    234      124
alice1  ab12    2342    12342
alice2   ab13    4450    24560
alice3  ab14    6558    36778
alice4   ab15    8666    48996
alice5  ab16    10774   61214
alice6   ab17    12882   73432
alice7  ab18    14990   85650
alice8   ab19    17098   97868
alice9  ab20    19206   110086
```

But I need to add column of `payment_type` to `group by` like this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    code,
    payment_type,
    avg(amount_a),
    avg(amount_b),
    avg(d.num_syjs),
    count(*) as total_person
FROM table_test n
GROUP BY code,name,
payment_type ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

And my expected output is as below:

[image: sql result with merged cells]

Comment: You cannot directly export to excel from mysql, only to delimited text file. You need to use an additional programming language to generate a formatted excel output.

Comment: @Shadow Hi, thanks, do you know how to export it in Python?

Comment: There are quite a few questions already on this here on SO, pls try one of those to get you started and ask a question if you get stuck.